# generation create-table DDL with CTE only ( no pg_dump, no functions) on Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, common-table-expression, ddl

I was wondering if generating the DDL of a target table of a specific schema is feasible using only SELECT query and CTE expression.

The idea is to produce a similar output than a pg_dump --schema-only aimed at the table.

Why ? I am constrained by the fact that I cannot write to the database, nor create function on it. I cannot use pg_dump either because I am not supposed to have rights on the shell or w/e.

I think I found a good first source to inspire myself with: https://github.com/lacanoid/pgddl

Comment: There is no reliable and robust way to generate a complete `CREATE TABLE` statement in SQL  Or do you only need column names and types?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

apparently using a combination of server side langage logic and a WITH query aimed toward the postgres catalog I managed to assemble the DDL I needed with all the properties and the constraint of the table.